# Wordpress remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses') doesn't work

Tags: php, html, wordpress, customization

I've tried using `remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses');` in my `functions.php` file to allow HTML tags in the author bios but it's not working. The HTML tags are converted to ansii < and > so it just outputs to the screen as raw html instead of rendering it. Any idea why this wouldn't work? I've tried putting this in my child theme `functions.php`, the parent theme `functions.php` as well as in a Snippets plugin with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you calling `remove_filter` with the same priority as the filter was added? `Important: To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.`

Comment: No idea really. All the examples I've seen to do this just say to add that line of code to your `functions.php` file and that's it. And I've seen so many tutorials on this I feel like it should have just been easier and worked. Not sure what the conflict is on my end.

Comment: I'd suggest you start by finding where `add_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses', ...` is called. It may or may not be added with a priority. If it is, find the priority, and pass that as the third parameter to `remove_filter`.

Comment: I did a global search and can't find an `add_filter` hook to match at all. But it's obviously filtering so it has to be active.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The issue was in my page template. The output for the author description was this `echo esc_html( $author->description );` which nullified my efforts to not escape the html. I moved the template file to my child theme and removed the `esc_html()` part so it's just `echo $author->description;` and now everything works great. Sorry to bother everyone, but glad I found the answer!